# How to delete a particular line in xml file based on the condition using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a problem and looking for a solution.

I want to delete the line but based on the condition. for example the xml file is

```
<app>
    .
    .
<process>
    <tag>any tag</tag>
    <trigger order="1" name="activity1" perform="y">
        <external>
                <action name="check_req"/>
                <action name="event"/>
        </external>
        <var name="type"/>
        <var name="user" />
          </trigger>
</process>
<process>
<tag>any tag</tag>
<trigger order="3" name="activity1" perform="y">
    <external>
            <action name="check_req"/>
            <action name="event"/>
            <action name="ckeck"/>
        </external>
        <var name="type"/>
        <var name="user" />
          </trigger>
</process>
<process>
<tag>any tag</tag>
<trigger order="2" name="activity1" perform="y">
    <external>
            <action name="event"/>
            <action name="ckeck"/>
        </external>
        <var name="type"/>
        <var name="user" />
          </trigger>
</process>
<process>
<tag>any tag</tag>
  <trigger order="1" name="activity1" perform="y">
    <external>
            <action name="check_req"/>
            <action name="event"/>
            <action name="ckeck"/>
        </external>
        <var name="type"/>
        <var name="user" />
     </trigger>
</process>
<process>
   <tag>any tag</tag>
   <trigger order="4" name="activity1" perform="y">
    <external>
            <action name="ckeck"/>
            <action name="check_req"/>
        </external>
        <var name="type"/>
        <var name="user" />
   </trigger>
</process>
</app>
```

So from this code I want to remove the line `<action name="ckeck"/>` whenever in the trigger these two action present

```
<action name="ckeck"/> 
<action name="ckeck_req"/>
```

or

```
<action name="ckeck_req"/>
<action name="ckeck"/>
```

So I have to remove the line  `<action name="ckeck"/>` only in the case the above two action comes together otherwise it will not remove any line.

So am new in python language so I am unable to do this thing. The problem is that it the file contains lots of trigger blocks some of them content both action block and some contain only one action block. The particular line is to remove only iff the given case occurs

Comment: means you have to remove`<action name="ckeck"/> ` tag if its next tag is `<action name="ckeck_req"/>` ?

Comment: It can be in any sequence. Sequence of the actions are not fix. In between the two action many action block also possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some xml parsing library, like [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or `lxml` .

Then you can use *XPATH* to find all `<external>` elements under `<trigger>` , and then get the `action` element with name property as `check_req` and `action` element with name property as `ckeck` . And then if both are not none, that means both childs exist, remove the element whose' name propert is `ckeck` and then save back the xml to some other file (or even same file). Example -

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
file = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = file.getroot()
for elem in root.findall('.//trigger/external'):
    check_req_elems = elem.find('./action[@name="check_req"]')
    check_elem = elem.find('./action[@name="ckeck"]')
    if check_req_elems is not None and check_elem is not None:
            elem.remove(check_elem)

file.write('b.xml')
```

---

Example/Demo -

My `a.xml` -

```
<app>
<process>
<tag>any tag</tag>
<trigger order="3" name="activity1" perform="y">
    <external>
            <action name="check_req"/>
            <action name="event"/>
            <action name="ckeck"/>
        </external>
        <var name="type"/>
        <var name="user" />
          </trigger>
</process>>
<process>
<tag>any tag</tag>
<trigger order="2" name="activity1" perform="y">
    <external>
            <action name="event"/>
            <action name="ckeck"/>
        </external>
        <var name="type"/>
        <var name="user" />
          </trigger>
</process>
</app>
```

The code -

```
>>> file = ET.parse('a.xml')
>>> root = file.getroot()
>>> for elem in root.findall('.//trigger/external'):
...     check_req_elems = elem.find('.//action[@name="check_req"]')
...     check_elem = elem.find('.//action[@name="ckeck"]')
...     if check_req_elems is not None and check_elem is not None:
...             elem.remove(check_elem)
...
>>> file.write('b.xml')
```

My `b.xml` becomes -

```
<app>
<process>
<tag>any tag</tag>
<trigger name="activity1" order="3" perform="y">
    <external>
            <action name="check_req" />
            <action name="event" />
            </external>
        <var name="type" />
        <var name="user" />
          </trigger>
</process>
<process>
<tag>any tag</tag>
<trigger name="activity1" order="2" perform="y">
    <external>
            <action name="event" />
            <action name="ckeck" />
        </external>
        <var name="type" />
        <var name="user" />
          </trigger>
</process>
</app>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for me. And learn new thing about the XML parsing.

Comment: Hi @Anand , this solution is removing the comments which is presented in the xml file. Please can you suggest any solution which will do not remove the comments.

Comment: You can take a look the XMLParser  here - http://effbot.org/zone/element-pi.htm (`PIParser`) , it would keep the comments in your xml . Try it out (use this parser in the `ET.parse()` function above.

Comment: I have looked at  XMLParser here - [link](effbot.org/zone/element-pi.htm) (PIParser) . It does work with ElementTree 1.2.X. But I have the latest one so I can not roll back to 1.2.

Comment: It does not work with the latest code? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Here is my execution output for that  [about][kml@kml-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$                     python withcomment.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "withcomment.py", line 1, in <module>
    import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
ImportError: No module named elementtree.ElementTree']

Comment: Wrong import, use `xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` .

Comment: Hi http://effbot.org/zone/element-pi.htm will change the xml file. it adds <documnet> in beginig of the xml file and adds </document> at the end of file.

Answer (score -1):

When the two actions arise in a trigger, are they always ordered in the same fashion, i.e. "ckeck" after "ckeck_req" and one line apart? If that is the case you could give the condition based on that, e.g.

```
action1 = "ckeck_req"
action2 = "ckeck"
with open(xmlfile, "r") as f:
    x = f.readlines()
y = [] # new list without the unwanted actions
for i in range(len(x)):
    if action2 in x[i] and action1 in x[i-2]:
        continue
    else:
        y.append(x[i])
```

Then you write the new list y to file. I just wrote this bit off the top of my head, so most likely there is a nicer way to do this. Now that I think about it you might want to look at [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Processing XML files as if they were line based text files isn't a good idea because they aren't. The same XML document might be formatted in just one line for instance.